# Selecting items in a listview

Tags: c#

I want to select a particular subitem in a row of a listview. For example if the row contains
5 subitems, if I click the 3rd subitem it only gets selected.

I solved the issue successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to detect which subitem the user clicked.

To achieve that check [this example](http://www.syncfusion.com/faq/winforms/files/WForum_ListViewSubItem.zip). Basically it will loop through the subitems collection of the ListViewItem and see whether the mouse pointer is over one of them.

Later... with the clicked subitem detected... you can change it ForeColor and Background to show it as "selected".

To be able to do that, you must set the ListViewItem's `UseItemStyleForSubItems` property to `false`. That will allow you to set background and other properties to a single subitem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListViewItem list;

for(int a=0;a<37;a++)
{
    list=new ListViewItem();
    list.UseItemStyleForSubItems=false;
    list.Text="vinoth";
    list.SubItems.Add("afdsdf");
    list.SubItems.Add("afddfdfdfdsdf");
    list.SubItems.Add("afdsdddsdf");
    listView1.Items.Add(list);
}

private void listView1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].BackColor=Color.Red;
}
```